# How to edit the time picker of material-ui-time-picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I have a `material-ui-time-picker` and I want to control this input, it works well, but I want to edit the time input from the keyboard and not when I click the input on the clock.

My code is :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TimePicker } from "material-ui-time-picker";
import { Input as Time, Dialog as Clock } from "@material-ui/core";

openDialog = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  closeDialog = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  handleDialogTimeChange = newValue => {
    const hours = newValue
      .getHours()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = newValue
      .getMinutes()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const textValue = hours + ":" + minutes;
    this.setState({ time: textValue });
  };
  handleKeyboardTimeChange = time => this.setState({ time });
  createDateFromTextValue = value => {
    const splitParts = value.split(":");
    return new Date(1970, 1, 1, splitParts[0], splitParts[1]);
  };
render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <Time
          value={this.state.time}
          onChange={this.handleKeyboardTimeChange}
          endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton onClick={this.openDialog}>
                <AccessTime />
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          }
          //}
        />
        <Clock maxWidth="xs" open={this.state.isOpen}>
          <TimePicker
            mode="24h"
            value={this.createDateFromTextValue(this.state.time)}
            onChange={this.handleDialogTimeChange}
            autoOk={true}
            cancelLabel=""
            okLabel=""
            placeholder=""
            disableUnderline={true}
          />
        </Clock>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/vm9wm19p27

When I run it, I get this input, but when I edit his value, the input will be disappeared.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `TimeInput` component doesn't allow this, but you can write your own component to create the exact behavior you want. Instead of importing `TimeInput` import `{ TimePicker }` from the package and create a custom component.

This is in no way fool proof but it will give you the basics to continue.
Working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/5l167pzrx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Input, InputAdornment, IconButton, Dialog, DialogActions } from '@material-ui/core';
import { TimePicker } from 'material-ui-time-picker';
import AccessTime from '@material-ui/icons/AccessTime';

function CustomDatePicker() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('10:10');

  const openDialog = () => setIsOpen(true);
  const closeDialog = () => setIsOpen(false);

  const handleDialogTimeChange = (newValue) => {
    const hours = newValue.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = newValue.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")
    const textValue = hours + ':' + minutes;
    setValue(textValue);
  }
  const handleKeyboardTimeChange = (event) => setValue(event.target.value);

  const createDateFromTextValue = value => {
    const splitParts = value.split(':');
    return new Date(1970, 1, 1, splitParts[0], splitParts[1]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Input
        value={value}
        onChange={handleKeyboardTimeChange}
        endAdornment={
        <InputAdornment position="end">
          <IconButton onClick={openDialog}>
            <AccessTime />
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      }
      />
      <Dialog maxWidth='xs' open={isOpen}>
        <TimePicker mode='24h' value={createDateFromTextValue(value)} onChange={handleDialogTimeChange} />
        <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={closeDialog} color='primary'>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={closeDialog} color='primary'>
          Ok
        </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomDatePicker
```

Comment: I try it, but when I click on the clock, the dialog will appears with the value of input, and when I click it, the timepicker will be displayed, can you check it on my sanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/ll59m5xx27 ?

Comment: Yep, because you used `TimeInput` instead of `TimePicker`

Comment: What is there to check? It works when I view it. The dialog doesn't close, but that's because there is no code that updates the `isOpen` variable to close it. And the reason the complete input disappears is because it throws an error. Always code with your console open. It's trying to split an invalid value.

Comment: I try to enter a valid value, but the input disappears

Comment: Yep, because it throws an error. In the `handleKeyboardTimeChange` function you're storing the event object (which you called time..) as the time. This can not be split like a string, because it is not a string. Try to learn how to use the developer tools of your browser, the errors in the console give a lot of direction to find out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

One solution component has been provided in their [Github repository](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/3933#issuecomment-323401999). Please check this out, it's an already know issue with material-ui and has already been accepted as a solution.This is the solution provided there incase the link becomes obsolete:

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {DatePicker, IconButton, TextField} from "material-ui";
import ActionDateRange from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/date-range';
import format from 'date-fns/format'
import parse from 'date-fns/parse'

export default class DatePickerField extends Component{

   constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        selectedDate: new Date(),
        dateText: format(new Date(), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
      };
   }

   handleChangeDatePicker = (event, date) => {
      this.setState({selectedDate: date, dateText:format(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')});
   };

   handleDateInputChange = (event, value) => {
      this.setState({dateText:value});
   };

   handleDateInputBlur = (value) => {
     let parsedDate = parse(value, 'MM/DD/YYYY');

     if(this.isADate(parsedDate)){
        this.setState({selectedDate:parsedDate});
     }
     else{
        this.setState({dateText:format(this.state.selectedDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')});
     }
   };

   isADate = (maybeDate) => {
      if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(maybeDate) === "[object Date]" ) {
         if ( isNaN( maybeDate.getTime() ) ) {
            return false;
         }
         else {
            return true;
         }
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   };

   render(){

      let dateInputWidth = "150px";
      let datePickerMargin = "-185px";

      return (
         <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
            <TextField
               style={{width:dateInputWidth}}
               value={this.state.dateText}
               onChange={this.handleDateInputChange}
               onBlur={(event) => this.handleDateInputBlur(event.currentTarget.value)}
            />

            <IconButton style={{opacity:"0.65"}}
                        onClick={() => this.datePicker.focus()}>
               <ActionDateRange />
            </IconButton>

            <div style={{width:"0px", height:"0px", marginLeft:datePickerMargin}}>
               <DatePicker
                  id="dataPicker"
                  floatingLabelText={''}
                  value={this.state.selectedDate}
                  errorText={''}
                  disabled={false}
                  formatDate={date => { return format(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') } }
                  autoOk
                  container="inline"
                  fullWidth
                  onChange={this.handleChangeDatePicker}
                  ref={c => {
                     this.datePicker = c
                  }}
               />
            </div>
         </div>
      )
   }

}
```

If you face the problem `Cannot find prepareStyles of undefined` error, please check if you have defined the theme as provider prior to any component usage, or else it won't work. Check this note:

> Beginning with v0.15.0, Material-UI components require a theme to be provided. The quickest way to get up and running is by using the MuiThemeProvider to inject the theme into your application context.

And this is the sample snippet to show how to accomplish that:

In your App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
 import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

 const App = () => (
   <MuiThemeProvider>
     <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
   </MuiThemeProvider>
 );

 ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

And in your `./MyAwesomeReactComponent.js` (that is the component you want to work witk):

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const MyAwesomeReactComponent = () => (
    <RaisedButton label="Default" />
);

export default MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

Please refer to their [official usage guide](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage) for further details.

Comment: provided the code from the link in case the link becomes obsolete. Thanks for the suggestion @Erik A

Comment: when I run it, I get : `Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined`, you can check it on my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/4qzkqzpv5x

Comment: Please check my answer, I have edited to include a possible source and solution of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example:
https://mui.wertarbyte.com/#timepicker

You can replace the button in the example by a `TextField` with an icon and only when you click on the icon open a [`TimePicker`](https://teamwertarbyte.github.io/material-ui-time-picker/#timepicker) instead of `TimeInput` or you can use the [`TimePicker`](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/timepicker) of the [material-ui-pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/timepicker) package

Material-ui-pickers demo: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/timepicker#keyboard-input

Comment: I try that, and I get `attempted import 'makeStyles'`

Comment: I get it for the second option !

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to do this:

1. use  `<KeyboardTimePicker />`
2. use `<KeyboardDateTimePicker />`