# How can I edit the value of the timepicker from the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui, timepicker

I have a `material-ui-time-picker` and I want to control this input, it works well, but I want to edit the time input from the keyboard and not when I click the input on the clock.

My code is :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TimePicker } from "material-ui-time-picker";
import { Input as Time, Dialog as Clock } from "@material-ui/core";

openDialog = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  closeDialog = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  handleDialogTimeChange = newValue => {
    const hours = newValue
      .getHours()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = newValue
      .getMinutes()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const textValue = hours + ":" + minutes;
    this.setState({ time: textValue });
  };
  handleKeyboardTimeChange = time => this.setState({ time });
  createDateFromTextValue = value => {
    const splitParts = value.split(":");
    return new Date(1970, 1, 1, splitParts[0], splitParts[1]);
  };
render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <Time
          value={this.state.time}
          onChange={this.handleKeyboardTimeChange}
          endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton onClick={this.openDialog}>
                <AccessTime />
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          }
          //}
        />
        <Clock maxWidth="xs" open={this.state.isOpen}>
          <TimePicker
            mode="24h"
            value={this.createDateFromTextValue(this.state.time)}
            onChange={this.handleDialogTimeChange}
            autoOk={true}
            cancelLabel=""
            okLabel=""
            placeholder=""
            disableUnderline={true}
          />
        </Clock>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/vm9wm19p27

When I run it, I get this input, but when I edit his value, the input will be disappeared.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: i cannot see anything runnable over above link

Comment: @KOTIOS can you check it ?

Comment: please add the code here since the link seems broken

Comment: Still Seems blank on browser output

Comment: @Ivanofuganda check my post, I add the code.

Comment: @KOTIOS check my post, I add the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit the the time picker of material-ui-time-picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742648/how-to-edit-the-the-time-picker-of-material-ui-time-picker)

Comment: yes @KOTIOS it 's my post, but I have the same issue

Comment: reopen the same Thread please or set bounty on it !

Comment: @KOTIOS I set bounty on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your sandbox and made a couple of adjustments. Though I've not fixed it - I'll just show you what's currently wrong.

https://codesandbox.io/s/j24rqql9n9

I modified two lines
In your constructor, I added

```
this.handleKeyboardTimeChange = this.handleKeyboardTimeChange.bind(this)
```

And your handleKeyboardTimeChange:

```
handleKeyboardTimeChange(event) {
  this.setState({ time: event.target.value });
}
```

This simply sets the state to exact value passed in from what you see there. No additional validation.

Comment: Example scenario that would require intervention: https://gyazo.com/face509b4be5ee955e803ede3104428c

Comment: Thank you @Caleb, How can I change the color of clock please ?

Comment: Kind of a moving target. I'm sure there's a better way with a react component to wrap it in a withStyles attribute and inject the style at compile time. But `div[class^="Clock-circle"] {  background: #f00; }` this line of CSS would do the trick. https://codesandbox.io/s/j24rqql9n9

Comment: If I understand my own code correctly, it just finds any class starting with `Clock-circle` and applies a background color. So this would not be applicable if you had multiple of these and you didn't want them all to be the same color

Comment: thank you, can you help me please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847842/how-to-change-the-value-of-input-dynamically