# How to change the value of input dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui, onchange

I have a dynamic inputs, which I can add and delete a row with inputs, there are inputs of material-ui for timepicker, which having an input with her icon of  a clock when I click on it the clock will appear. but the values of this input cannot change with the clock.

My code is :

```
import { TimePicker } from "material-ui-time-picker";
import {
  Input as Time,
  Dialog as Clock,
  DialogActions,
  Button as ButtonOk
} from "@material-ui/core";
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpenS: false,
      isOpenE: false,
      start: moment().format("HH:MM"),
      end: moment().format("HH:MM"),
      tranches: [
        { start: moment().format("HH:MM"), end: moment().format("HH:MM") }
      ]
    };

    this.ajouterTranche = this.ajouterTranche.bind(this);
    this.supprimerTranche = this.supprimerTranche.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyboardStartChange = this.handleKeyboardStartChange.bind(this);
  }


  openDialogS = () => this.setState({ isOpenS: true });
  closeDialogS = () => this.setState({ isOpenS: false });
  backdropClickS = () => this.setState({ isOpenS: false });
  handleDialogStartChange = (i, newValue) => {
    const hours = newValue
      .getHours()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = newValue
      .getMinutes()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const textValue = hours + ":" + minutes;
    // this.setState({ start: textValue });
    this.state.tranches[i] = Object.assign({}, this.state.tranches[i], {
      start: textValue
    });
    this.setState({
      tranches: this.state.tranches
    });
  };

  handleKeyboardStartChange = (i, event) => {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.tranches.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[i] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[i], {
      start: event.target.value
    });
    this.setState({
      tranches: rowDataCopy
    });
  };
  createDateFromTextValue = (i, value) => {
    const splitParts = value.split(":");
    return new Date(1970, 1, 1, splitParts[0], splitParts[1]);
  };

  openDialogE = () => this.setState({ isOpenE: true });
  closeDialogE = () => this.setState({ isOpenE: false });
  handleDialogEndChange = newValue => {
    const hours = newValue
      .getHours()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = newValue
      .getMinutes()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const textValue = hours + ":" + minutes;
    this.setState({ end: textValue });
  };
  handleKeyboardEndChange = (i, event) => {
    // On va copier le tableau de tranches
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.tranches.slice(0);
    // On va jouter cette valeur changée au tableau de tranches
    rowDataCopy[i] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[i], {
      end: event.target.value
    });
    this.setState({
      tranches: rowDataCopy
    });
  };
  createDateFromTextValue = value => {
    const splitParts = value.split(":");
    return new Date(1970, 1, 1, splitParts[0], splitParts[1]);
  };


  ajouterTranche = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      tranches: [...prevState.tranches, ""]
    }));
  };

  supprimerTranche = idx => () => {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.tranches.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.splice(1, 1);
    this.setState({
      tranches: rowDataCopy
    });
  };
render() {

    console.log(this.state.start);
    return (

      <div>
        {this.state.tranches.map((el, i) => (
          <Row key={i}>
            <Col span={12} />
            <Col span={12}>
              <Row>
                <Col span={8}>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <label className="pt-label .modifier">
                    <strong>Heure de début</strong>
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <Time
                    value={el.start}
                    onChange={time => this.handleKeyboardStartChange(i, time)}
                    style={heure}
                    disableUnderline={true}
                    inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
                    endAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="end" style={{ opacity: "0.4" }}>
                        <IconButton onClick={this.openDialogS}>
                          <AccessTime />
                        </IconButton>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                  <Clock
                    maxWidth="xs"
                    open={this.state.isOpenS}
                    onBackdropClick={this.closeDialogS}
                  >
                    <TimePicker
                      mode="24h"
                      value={this.createDateFromTextValue(this.state.start)}
                      onChange={time => this.handleDialogStartChange(i, time)}
                    />
                    <DialogActions>
                      <ButtonOk onClick={this.closeDialogS} color="primary">
                        Ok
                      </ButtonOk>
                    </DialogActions>
                  </Clock>
                  <br />
                </Col>
                <Col span={8}>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <label className="pt-label .modifier">
                    <strong>Heure de fin</strong>
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <Time
                    value={el.end}
                    onChange={time => this.handleKeyboardEndChange(i, time)}
                    style={heure}
                    disableUnderline={true}
                    inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
                    endAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="end" style={{ opacity: "0.4" }}>
                        <IconButton onClick={this.openDialogS}>
                          <AccessTime />
                        </IconButton>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                  <Clock
                    maxWidth="xs"
                    open={this.state.isOpenE}
                    onBackdropClick={this.closeDialogE}
                  >
                    <TimePicker
                      mode="24h"
                      value={this.createDateFromTextValue(this.state.end)}
                      onChange={this.handleDialogEndChange}
                    />
                    <DialogActions>
                      <ButtonOk onClick={this.closeDialogE} color="primary">
                        Ok
                      </ButtonOk>
                    </DialogActions>
                  </Clock>
                  <br />
                </Col>
                <Col span={8}>
                  {i === 0 ? (
                    <>
                      <br />
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                      &nbsp;
                      <Icon
                        type="plus-circle"
                        theme="twoTone"
                        twoToneColor="#52c41a"
                        onClick={this.ajouterTranche}
                      />
                      <br />
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <Icon
                        type="close-circle"
                        theme="twoTone"
                        twoToneColor="red"
                        onClick={this.supprimerTranche(i)}
                      />
                      <Icon
                        type="plus-circle"
                        theme="twoTone"
                        twoToneColor="#52c41a"
                        onClick={this.ajouterTranche}
                      />
                      <br />
                    </>
                  )}
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}
      </div>


    );
  }
}
```

My sandbox code is :https://codesandbox.io/s/182oy5995l

When I put a value on the input and I click on the clock, I get the moment value of the clock and not the value which I put on the input.
I want when I change the time from the clock, the input will be change and vice versa.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to set you on the right track. I think if you get this, you'll be able to quickly fix the rest of the problems. I don't really know what you're trying to do with the start and end though. So what I've done will only work on the timepicker and you can use this to fix the keyboard thing again.

Here is my forked version
https://codesandbox.io/s/2xm39130kn

When you call `handleDialogStartChange` with multiple objects, you can't just modify one state. Unless they're all supposed to share the same time. That seems pointless.

I modified your timepicker onChange function to `onChange={time => this.handleDialogStartChange(i, time)}` so you can push the index as well so you know which one you want to work with.

I modified your timepicker value function to `value={this.createDateFromTextValue(el.start)}` so you're referencing the individual element, not the original state variable.

Then in `andleDialogStartChange` modify the the state of the tranches where you're storing these times, using that index. You'll get a warning not to modify state like this, but so long as you're using it in conjunction with setState, `this.setState({ tranches: this.state.tranches });`, it's a legal operation.

```
handleDialogStartChange = (i, newValue) => {
    const hours = newValue
      .getHours()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = newValue
      .getMinutes()
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0");
    const textValue = hours + ":" + minutes;
    this.state.tranches[i].start = textValue;
    this.state.tranches[i].end = textValue;
    this.setState({ tranches: this.state.tranches });
    this.setState({ start: textValue });
  };
```

Comment: the start is the input of the start and the end is the another input, which when I click on plus, one row will be added with the inputs of start and end

Comment: end is supposed to be whatever you just changed it to?

Comment: try out the sandbox and tell me what doesn't work like you expect?

Comment: When I put a value on the input and I click on the clock, I get the moment value of the clock and not the value which I put on the input. I want when I change the time from the clock, the input will be change and vice versa. https://codesandbox.io/s/182oy5995l

Comment: can you help me please ?

Comment: I'm not sure what change you made that now the dialog pulls the last created row's value into the timepicker. I don't know how to fix that. This is my current version where that's the only thing that doesn't work I think. https://codesandbox.io/s/mznj5nkopp

Comment: Thank you @Caleb, can you help me on this  please ? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870078/how-to-passing-data-from-component-to-another-component-on-reactjs-using-map

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve **I get the clock and I chose the hour, but it's not changed** make a small change **value={el.start}** to **value={this.state.start}**.

Comment: But, all the input of the rows will be the same value when I make `value={this.state.start}`