# How to passing data from component to another component on reactJs using map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-component

I have a [react-big-calendar](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html), I want when I click on new event, the dialog of the hour will be having the values of the hour clicked on the new event, for example, I click the mouse from 07:30 to 08:30,  so I want to get this hour on my dialog as the value of the input of `start` and `end` state, but, I have the same dialog by clicking on the button "Ajouter disponibilité" which his position is above of the calendar, when I click it I will have the hour of the moment, and at both of them I can change it with the clock.

My code sandbox is :

https://codesandbox.io/s/9llpm579py

When I run it, I get the same value is moment for a both of them.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426078/reactjs-passing-state-value-from-one-component-to-another

Comment: @mojtabaramezani No, it's not the same case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xl25y616j

Because you're passing the required format for those text fields in as parameters to `handleAjouter = (start, end)`, you can just bind them to your first element's start and end. You could use moment like you had, but it doesn't seem necessary.

```
handleAjouter = (start, end) => {
    this.state.tranches[0].start = start;
    this.state.tranches[0].end = end;
    this.setState({
      start: moment(start).format("HH:mm"),
      end: moment(end).format("HH:mm"),
      clickDisponibilite: true,
      tranches: this.state.tranches,
      openPopupAjout: true
    });
  };
```

Because your initial element, while it gets its initial value from start and end, its values are inside tranches[0].

So now it pulls those values in https://gyazo.com/d0f887a0fa3d4dfeff56919a7cf94b28

Comment: Thank you @Caleb, but when I click on the button above of the calendar, all are dissapear, but I want when I click it, I get the `moment().format("HH:mm)` value of input

Comment: Can you use redux? I will try without. I'm not sure you can do two way binding without a store.

Comment: Redux works like a data storage you can just use however. Looking at where you're headed with this, it will make your life easier. It's like a variable holder that any of your components can send or receive data. If you used it, you could say: when the time is changed in the popup, set tranches[i] start and stop to values in your redux store and just get those values in Agenda to make the new calendar entry.

Comment: Thank you @Caleb, can you help me on this please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003028/how-to-send-the-date-of-calendar-to-another-calendar-with-reactjs