# this.props.history.push is working just after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, ref, react-ref

I have a react-big-calendar, which has a button when I click on it, his modal will appear, and I have also a calendar icon button which redirects me to another URL /planning.

I have a dialog (AjouterDisponibilite) and I call it with the ref on my component Agenda.

And the calendar icon has an `onClick` event which I try:

```
this.props.history.push('/planning');
```

but when I run it and I click on the icon, the URL is directed correct, but I get an `error` as shown below:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleAjouter' of null` and 
 `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method`

and after I refresh this page, it works.

My code is: https://codesandbox.io/s/xw01v53oz

How can I fix it?

Comment: Props are immutable in React. Don't alter them like that. If you want to keep data around for use in the component, use state, or of course, pass down from a parent.

Comment: @rrd How can I fix it please ? can you check my sandbox ?

Comment: Mutating props is not a problem in this case. `this.props.history` points to react-router history object and calling `push` is one of the recommended way to redirect using react-router. More details: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: Which file/line throws the error? The error means that you try to update state on an unmounted component. It's not an routing issue in first place.

Comment: @sschmeck the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleAjouter' of null` on the component `Agenda`

Comment: With `<AjouterDisponibilite ref={this.ModalAjout}` /> the method `ModalAjout` is called without a parameter. The method tries to destructure the `null`. Seems a `ref`usage issue.

Comment: Yes exactly @sschmeck but how can I fix it please ?

Comment: Haven't used `ref` yet. You could improve the question pointing to the `ref` issue. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is improper use of Refs. Refs are designed to keep references to DOM-elements and component instances, not their functions.

Components with a `ref` prop will assign themself to the value of the prop (or call the function with itself as an argument) when they are mounted, and they will do the same with a `null` reference when they are unmounted.

With this knowledge, you have to change your code of the `Agenda` component as follows:

```
ModalAjout = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
        this.ajout = ref.handleAjouter;
    } else {
        this.ajout = null;
    }
}

ModalAjoutb = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
        this.ajoutb = ref.handleAjouter;
    } else {
        this.ajoutb = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: and I call his component with `<AjouterDisponibilite ref={(evt) => this.ModalAjout({evt})}/>` ?

Comment: I try that, but it doesn't working can you check it please ? https://codesandbox.io/s/xw01v53oz

Comment: No, you don´t call it, you just pass it to the prop `ref={this.ModalAjout}` as it was before.

Comment: can you check my sandbox please ? https://codesandbox.io/s/xw01v53oz I try how you say and it doesn't working.

Comment: I have a method `newEvent`, which calls `this.ajout(
      this.state.startDisponibilite,
      this.state.endDisponibilite,
      this.state.dateDisponibilite
    );`

Comment: The error you now have is because of undefined state variables in your `AjouterDisponibilite` component and has nothing to do with the question asked here. But because it is a quick solution: `tranchesC` is not defined in your state. And you should change `onClick={this.ajoutb}` to `onClick={() => this.ajoutb()}`

Comment: Thank you @Rallen, it works well. Can you help me on this please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003028/how-to-send-the-date-of-calendar-to-another-calendar-with-reactjs

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this you can add this code:

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
```

What is doing? It's initializing the history with one value after it was loaded the first time, then you don't need to do the refresh.

In my case I did this while I was developing an Android App and had some modals that I wanted to close with the back button to provide a more native experience.

Answer (score 2):

I fix it, by adding:

```
<AjouterDisponibilite ref={(evt) => this.ModalAjout({evt})} start={this.state.startDisponibilite} end={this.state.endDisponibilite} date={this.state.dateDisponibilite}/>
<AjouterDisponibilite ref={(evt) => this.ModalAjoutb({evt})} />
```

The method `ModalAjout`  must have a parameter.